# How to upload image files from gallery using retrofit 2?

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am a little new to android and have been trying to send data to server using retrofit 2.What i am doing is selecting images from gallery and getting their paths but i have a less knowledge of how uploading works.

I have multiple images uri from gallery and using this function i get their paths

```
public String getImagePath(Uri uri) {
    String selectedImagePath;
    // 1:MEDIA GALLERY --- query from MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null) {
        int column_index = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        selectedImagePath = cursor.getString(column_index);
    } else {
        selectedImagePath = null;
    }

    if (selectedImagePath == null) {


        selectedImagePath = uri.getPath();
    }
    return selectedImagePath;
}
```

this gives me the paths like this.

for example: storage/emulated/0/Download/cheque_image.jpeg

do i need only these paths to create  files

```
File file = new File(getimagepath(uri));



 RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(getContentResolver().getType(fileUri)), file);

    return MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(partName, file.getName(),requestBody);
```

Does the file created from path is enough to be uploaded using multipart or should inputstream from uri is used to be passed inside file and then to upload.

```
OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
```

Comment: you can look this : https://github.com/hidrodixtion/Example-Retrofit-Image-Upload/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/projectbox/uploadfile/MainActivity.java

Comment: yes but i want to get clear that there is no need for inputstream uri to be used  only the created file with path is enough to send the data to the server.